# Inserting a function into dx

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Sometimes when we calculate an indefinite integral in class we insert a function into $dx$, we always insert the primitive of the function into dx.   ($f'(x)dx=d(f(x))$)

A simple example is:

$\int {\cot xdx}  = \int {\frac{{\cos x}}{{\sin x}}dx}  = \int {\frac{{d\left( {\sin x} \right)}}{{\sin x}}}  = \left[ {t = \sin x} \right] = \int {\frac{{dt}}{t}}  =  - \frac{1}{{{t^2}}}+C =  - \frac{1}{{{{\sin }^2}\left( x \right)}}+C$

I'm not sure I understand the meaning of doing such a thing? Can it always be done?
I would like to understand $dx$ once and for all.

Comment: Yes, but why does the "trick" $dxf'(x)=d(f(x))$ always work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this works and is not just a trick, but formally correct, is that you can think of $d$ as being the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) operator.  The way $d$ works on a differentiable function of one variable is just as you have written, $d(f(x))=\frac{df}{dx} \cdot$dx

Comment: So if I get it correctly, it does require $f'(x)$ to be integrable and that f(x) is it's primitive function. in other words requires $f'(x)$ to be continous?

Comment: Yes it requires $f'$ to have primitive $f$, and in every case I've seen people require $f$ to be smooth or at least have $f'$ continuous when defining $d$.

Comment: Something to note is that $dx$ and dx are different (but the first evaluates to the second).  The first is applying the operator $d$ to the function $x$ while the second is thought of as an arrow pointing in the positive $x$ direction whose base is moving along the interval of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $g(y)$ is a continuous function of $f$, and $f(x)$ is a continuously differentiable function of $x$.

Now, we propose that

$$\int g(f)\,df=\int g(f(x))\frac{df(x)}{dx}\,dx \tag 1$$

The left-hand side of $(1)$ represents a function whose derivative with respect to $f$ is $g(f)$.  The right-hand side of $(1)$ represents a function whose derivative with respect to $x$ is $g(f(x))\,\frac{df(x)}{dx}$.

But, from the chain-rule, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int g(f)\,df\right)&=\left.\frac{d}{df}\left(\int g(f)\,df\right)\right|_{f=f(x)}\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)\\\\
&=g(f(x))\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int g(f(x))\frac{df(x)}{dx}\,dx \right) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Comparing the left-hand and right-hand sides of $(2)$, we have

$$\int g(f)\,df=\int g(f(x))\frac{df(x)}{dx}\,dx+C$$

Inasmuch as the integration constant is arbitrary, we have established the proposed equivalence of $(1)$ and therefore, $\frac{df(x)}{dx}\,dx=d(f(x))$ when $f(x)$ is a continuously differentiable function of $x$.